# MYSQL Filling one table from another

Tags: mysql

I am having two tables

1. question_bank(ques_id,question,answer,a,b,c,d)
2. random_question_bank(user_id,q1,q2,............,q20)

I have filled the user_id from users.

Now, i want to fill the q1,q2,.......q20 with ques_id(randomly) for every user_id.

Please, HELP with the code.

```
$result_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO random_question_bank(user_id) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user_id']."')");
if($result_user)
    echo('<br />user name inserted<br />');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_bank ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
$q = array();
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO random_question_bank(q.'$i') 
         VALUES('".$row['ques_id']."')
        WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    $result_ques = mysql_query($sql);
    $i++;
    if($result_ques)
         echo('<br />q'.$i.'<br />');
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
$result_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO random_question_bank(user_id) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user_id']."')");
if($result_user)
echo('<br />user name inserted<br />');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_bank ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");    
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sql = "Update random_question_bank set q.'$i' 
     ='".$row['ques_id']."' WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$result_ques = mysql_query($sql);
$i++;
if($result_ques)
     echo('<br />q'.$i.'<br />');
$i++;
}
```

According to my knowledge, you can not use where clause with insert statement. Hope it will work for you.